# Is there a way to differentiate between a server being down and a URL not existing with urllib?

Tags: python, urllib

I am writing a python program to show whether a website is up and running or not. Here is my code till now:

```
import urllib.request

weburl = str(input('Enter the URL: '))
#print(urllib.request.urlopen("https://"+ weburl).getcode())


try:
    webcode = urllib.request.urlopen("https://"+ weburl).getcode()
    if webcode == 200:
        print('Website is working')
except:
    print("Website is down or doesn't exist")
```

However, if the website is down, or it doesn't exist, the code returns a URLError for both scenarios. This is the error for the server being down

```
Exception has occurred: URLError
<urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
  File "C:\Programming\Python\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(urllib.request.urlopen("https://"+ weburl).getcode())
```

and here is the exception when the URL doesn't exist:

```
Exception has occurred: URLError
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
  File "C:\Programming\Python\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(urllib.request.urlopen("https://"+ weburl).getcode())
```

How can I differentiate between the server being down and the URL never existing in the first place? I have thought about using the time between the request and return in the 'except:' line because it is considerably faster when the website doesn't exist at all, however, I'm not sure if this would work due to people having different internet speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of catching all possible Exceptions when calling the `urlopen` method, you should catch the `urllib.error.HTTPError` one, which can tell you the status code of the response, as follows:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError

weburl = input('Enter the URL: ')

try:
    urllib.request.urlopen(weburl)
except HTTPError as error:
    if error.code == 404:
        print("The server exists but the endpoint does not!")
    else:
        print("The server exists but there was an Internal Error!")
except URLError as error:
    print("The server does not exist!")
```

Of course, appart from the HTTPError, other exceptions can be thrown like `ValueError`, `URLError`, etcetera, so just in case you want to handle them you could also catch them.

**EDIT:** I did not explain it well, sorry. The URLError is also raised when a server does not exist, so you should also catch it. I thought you only wanted to check if a concrete endpoint of an existing server existed or not, but if you want to also check if the server exists, you should also catch catch the URLError exception.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this code doesn't work. When there is no url i get the error: 

<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

 and when the server is down, i get the error: 

<urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

Both are URLErrors

Comment: That's quite strange, when I test it on my PC it works without any problems. Could you please tell your Python version and Operating System?

Comment: It's Windows 10 and Python 3.8.5

Comment: If the error is the same as the one you mentioned in the initial question, the failing line is `print(urllib.request.urlopen("https://"+ weburl).getcode())`. You need to comment out this line because it executes the `urlopen` method without catching exceptions. Did you copy/pasted and executed exactly the same code I posted?

Comment: It works now. I'm not sure what went wrong the first time. Thanks alot.